# How to make datalabels fit inside the bars

Tags: reactjs, react-chartjs

I have used react-chartjs-2 for creating bar chart. The problem I am facing is with datalabels. Datalables are displayed inside each bar. In normal display they are fitting inside the bars. But when screen size is increased beyond 140% then datalabels are getting spilled out of bars. I tried to follow several solution, but nothing helped me.

See the attached screenshot:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yp3cw.png)

Here is my code:

```
let test= [];
    let max= [];
    let minmalvalue;
    this.props.chartData.datasets.map((item)=>{
      if(item.label != "% Coverage")
     test = test.concat(item.data);
     max = test.reduce(function(a, b) {
      return Math.max(a, b);
  });
    });
    minmalvalue = 0.03*max;
    let finalvalue=Math.round(minmalvalue);
    finalvalue=finalvalue+1;
     console.log(finalvalue);
    let options = {
      tooltips: {
        enabled: true
      },
      scales: {
        xAxes: [{
          barPercentage: 0.8,
          categoryPercentage: 0.7,
          stacked: true,
          gridLines: {
            display:false
          }
        }],
        yAxes: [
          {
            id: 'y-axis-1',
            stacked: true,
            display: true,
            position: 'left',
            gridLines: {
              display:false
            }
          },
          {
            id: 'y-axis-2',
            stacked: true,
            display: true,
            position: 'right',
            ticks: {
              min: 0,
              max: 100,
              callback: function (value) {return value + "%";}
            },
            gridLines: {
              display:false
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      legend: {
        display: true,
        labels: {
          fontColor: "#000000"
        }
      },
      plugins:  {
        datalabels: {
          display: function(context) {
            return (context.dataset.data[context.dataIndex] !== 0 && context.dataset.data[context.dataIndex] !== "0" && context.dataset.data[context.dataIndex] >= finalvalue); // or >= 1 or ...
          },
          color: 'black',
          align: 'bottom',
          anchor: 'bottom',
          padding:'0px',
          font: {
            weight: 'bold',
            size :15
         },
          formatter: function (datasets, data) {
            if(datasets === 0 || datasets === "0") {
              return;
            }
            if(data.dataset.label === "% Coverage"){
              console.log("datasets", datasets);
              return datasets + "%";
            }
          }
        }
      }
    };
```

I want datalabels to fit inside the bars. Even in case of zoom-in/zoom-out, it shouldn't go beyond the boundaries of bar.